# Downloading a zip file from XPath and saving it to a specific folder

Tags: xml, xpath, vbscript

I am writing a VBScript automation code to download a .xls file from a website after the required authorization. Once I login, I need to click a specific download button, but the "id" for that particular element is not available in the HTML source code. When I researched I got to know about XPath. So now I need to click that download button by using given PAath of the element.

Sample code which I wrote:

```vb
Const strURL = "https://gtf.com/"
Const strID = "abc"
Const strPswd = "xyz"

Set objIE = CreateObject( "InternetExplorer.Application" )
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.Navigate2 strURL

Do While objIE.Busy
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 1000

objShell.SendKeys "{TAB 0}"
WScript.Sleep 100
objShell.SendKeys strID
WScript.Sleep 100
objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 100
objShell.SendKeys strPswd
WScript.Sleep 100
objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}" 
WScript.Sleep 100

objIE.Navigate2 "https://gts.com/download/asc"
WScript.Sleep 100

Set objNode = objDoc.selectSingleNode("//*[@id="folderfilelisttable"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[13]/a[2]/span")
```

I don't know how to click that XPath location (in `Set objNode`) and then I need to store that file in a given location (folder) and then convert that .xls file to .xlsx, all by using the above code.

Comment: I don't know vbscript, but I would rather replicate what the button click does instead of using a real browser. You could record the requests from some browser's debug tools and just send the same ones. That way you have better control over what to do and you can get rid of all the sleeps.

Comment: Your XPath string is broken. Either double the nested double quotes or change them to single quotes. As for clicking, does `objNode.Click` work?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers                                                                                     //*[@id="folderfilelisttable"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[13]/a[2]/span       This is the copied xpath from browser. I have already tried single quotes and objNode.Click and it's not working